# Conditional formatting cells within a date range in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-2010

I want to do this pseudo formula  below:

```
IF CELL VALUE < TODAY() + 60 , THEN FORMAT CELL RED
```

to these spreadsheet cells :

[image]

I am having trouble with Conditional Formatting in EXCEL 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Excel, do the following:

- Go to the **Home** Tab
- Select the values which need to be conditionally formatted
- Click **Conditional Formatting** >> **New Rule...**
- In the dialog, select *Format only cells that contain*
- At the bottom of the dialog:

  - Change the first drop-down to *Cell Value*
  - Change the second drop-down to *Less Than*
  - Change the third block to be `=Today() + 60`
- Click <kbd>Format...</kbd>, set the font to RED, then click <kbd>OK</kbd>
- On the *New Formatting Rule* dialog, click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Once you Apply, you will see your highlighting show up.

Comment: Where is `Conditional Formatting`?

Answer (score 0):

There is Conditional Formatting button in Styles menu in Excel 2007. Should be something similar in 2010, no?

Comment: Yes I have been trying to use the Styles/Conditional Formatting menu items--too many choice they give, and their logic in the UI language used seems unclear. Although my problem, as shown by my pseudo-code formula seems straight forward, I have not had luck trying to figure it out. Any assistance would grateful. Cheers.

Comment: Where did you get that pseudo code from? Does Excel let you edit it directly?

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck with this question over at the [superuser stackexchange](https://superuser.com/search?q=excel+conditional+format).  A quick grok of the questions there reference [this page on conditional formatting](http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/condfmt.htm).