# Using either IF statements or conditional formatting using either font color or cell highlight for dates

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need to know how to use either conditional formatting or an IF statement to format dates.

Specifically, I need any date that is 1 year old or older from today's date to show up in red font. For example, if the date in the spreadsheet is 3/13/13, and the date today is 3/13/14, I would like it to turn red. Also if the date has been longer than one year (if the date is 3/1/13, it should still show up red).

I also need to use the same idea with basic numbers. For example if the number is 12-15, the font should show up blue, if it is 16-19, it should show up orange, etc.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Tons of hits on google for "conditional format date" - please search *before* asking here...  Second part of your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

See here [Conditional formatting cells within a date range in Excel 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597568/conditional-formatting-cells-within-a-date-range-in-excel-2010) for an idea of how to format based on a changing date.  You would use  either TODAY()-365 or DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())) as the lower bound for checking.

The second part regarding formatting based on range is covered here:  [Excel: Conditional formatting for clusters of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492425/excel-conditional-formatting-for-clusters-of-values)